# how to add property to an EmberJS arrayController

Tags: ember.js

How do I go about adding a controller property to each item in an arrayController?

For example, if I named the property "isExpanded", I want to be able to do something like this in the template:

```
{{#each controller}}
    {{#if isExpanded}}
        expanded content
    {{else}}
        non-expanded content
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Please note that I cannot use an ObjectController in the real application; please see my comment after Kingpin2's respond below.

Answer (score 1):

Use an item controller, and add the property to the item controller.  It is a controller that will be used for each item in the controller list.

```
App.ColorsController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'color'
});

App.ColorController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  isExpanded: false
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/iSaJELug/2/edit

If you are talking about arraycontroller scope of the isExpanded, it's just as simple:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/iSaJELug/3/edit

```
{{#each item in controller}}
  {{#if controller.isExpanded}}
    <li>Color: {{item.color}} and Class: {{item.class}}</li>
  {{else}}
    <li>Color: {{item.color}}</li>
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}

App.IndexController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  isExpanded: false,
});
```

One last note, when you just say `{{each controller}}` you are changing the scope from the controller being in scope to the item being in scope, and if you wanted to access the controller properties you would then need to qualify the property with `controller.isExpanded`.

Comment: No, in my real application, I need an array controller.  The arraycontroller is associated with a parent route, which has a subroute.

So extrapolating my example in the original posting, I would want to use the "isExpanded" controller property to decide whether to expand each of the array member in the arraycontroller.

Comment: I didn't say not to use an array controller, I said to use an item controller as well.  Where does the isExpanded live?  is it on each item in the controller, or is it controlling whether or not all of the items exist or not?

Comment: I've added another example above where it lives on the array controller

Comment: I've tried adding the property to the associated itemController but still couldn't access it inside the each block.  I speculate I'm not using the correct syntax.  Using just {{isExpanded}} didn't work.  I've also tried {{controlname.isExpanded}}, which didn't work either.  What's the correct syntax?

Comment: Additionally, you can add an if statement around the each loop, and just create 2 each loops.

Comment: Which would probably be more performant, single if statement, instead of checking during each iteration.